# Display image over top of all DIV sections on page

Tags: html, css, joomla, z-index

Joomla-based website with DIV sections dividing the page within the template.

I need to display a graphic that displays on top of all content on the page.  Using position: relative or position: absolute, it only adjusts the position within the current DIV section.

Using position: fixed, I am able to set its actual position, which is great.  However, regardless of my z-index, some DIVs it appears above, others behind.

At a loss as to how to display this image over top of everything on the screen regardless as to its DIV, z-index, etc.

Comment: Use position absolute but adjust changes caused by not displaying img in that place by for eg margin, padding, height etc

Comment: Show some code and what browser are you using? Some browsers treat z-index differently. Some browsers give the parent of any element z-index priority. The get around this, Make your image closer the to root element. Or outside the parent containing the stuff you want it to be over.

Comment: http://star991.com/index.php/eeo

That is the working page on a live site - not the final destination for the 'image' but allows for testing on a barely-visited page.

It's in "absolute" mode now with negative values for top/left, but still falls "underneath" a bunch of elements on the page.

This is an issue on both FF/Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Use position absolute but adjust changes caused by not displaying img in that flow by for eg margin, padding, height etc. If you are floating img you will need to fix position too.

```
<div>  
    <div>before img</div>
    <img class="img--absolute" src="http://placekitten.com/50/60"/>
    <div  class="absolute-fix">after img</div>
</div>

.img--absolute{
    position: absolute;
}

.absolute-fix{
    margin-top: 70px;
}

<div class="img-container--float-fix">beffor img</div>
    <div>before img</div>
    <img class="img--float img--absolute" src="http://placekitten.com/50/60"/>
    <div class="absolute--float-fix">after img</div>
</div>


.img-container--float-fix{
    position: relative;
}

.absolute--float-fix{
    padding-right: 60px;
}

.img--float.img--absolute{
    right: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/o5sboe1s/

Comment: Unfortunately, inside the Joomla framework, I don't have access to change the CSS values for other containers.  I'm attempting to do this modifying only the img I am attempting to place on the screen.  You can see the demo code live at http://star991.com/index.php/eeo

Comment: Joomla is CMS not framework. Of course you can modify CSS (google it). In the worst case you can include css properties inline in HTML like this: <div style="margin-top:10px">